# Is there a way to display <mark> with draftjs?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I have a draft.js RTE, and I would like to be able to insert `<mark>` (or `<span>` with background-color) on certain positions in user's entry when he clicks a button.

I am currently able to display what the user typed and to change the text being displayed, but I'm unabled to add `<mark>`, `<span>`, `<div>` or even `<p>` (I can only add `<strong>`, `<h1>` ...)

Is there a way for me to achieve that ?

My code right now :

```
const sampleMarkup =
    '<mark>I want this message to be highlighted</mark>';

    this.setState({
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
        stateFromHTML(sampleMarkup)
        )
    });
```

(I am currently using draft-js-import-html to try and achieve that)

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am also looking for the same